# Get divs to fill the line and don't push eachother down

Tags: css, inline

Need help with a problem I can't solve myself.

I'm trying to make a div which is a menu, but when text gets too long it pushes the divs down and I need them to stay in place and instead get more height.

**css:**

```
.menu-item {
  width: 100%;
}

.menu-title {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
#number {
  display: inline-block;
  background: blue;
  color: #fff;
}
#dish {
  display: inline-block;
  background: red;
}
#price {
  background: green;
  display: inline-block;
}

.menu-ingredients {

}
#ingredients {

}
```

**html:**

```
<div class="menu-item">
  <div class="menu-title">
    <div id="number">23</div>
    <div id="dish">Souvlaki</div>
    <div id="price">495 kr</div>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-ingredients">
    <div id="ingredients">Pizza, hamburger, cucumber, tomato</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="menu-item">
  <div class="menu-title">
    <div id="number">40</div>
    <div id="dish">RAVIOLI CON PIPIENO DI GRANICHI E RICOTTA AL FINOCCHIO E SALSINA DI ARRAGOSTA

</div>
    <div id="price">9000 kr</div>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-ingredients">
    <div id="ingredients">Ravioli filled with crab and ricotta. Servec with minicucumber and cheese from Gotland. Shrimps toghether with peanuts and pumpkin</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[See fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tm4aLpje/3/)`display: inline-block;`
* When you open the fiddle and resize the window to a smaller width the divs end, but beneath each other *

Is there some way to get the blue, red and green div on the same line, increasing height to fit the text instead? Like in the first example

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a [**link to an example or site**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it), if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this

```
.menu-title {
  width: 100%;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
}
```

Comment: @Jonathan, this is a must-read https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: You answered before i could even understand the question ... have my upvote x)

Comment: Really good information in the links.
Thank you very much.
/* I SHALL LEARN */

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox (see **Head In Cloud**'s answer) is probably the best solution but you may also consider adding a `% width` (like 80%) in `#dish` like that (also you may add `vertical-align:middle;`):

```css
.menu-item {
  width: 100%;
}

.menu-title {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
#number {
  display: inline-block;
  background: blue;
  color: #fff;
}
#dish {
  display: inline-block;
  background: red;
  width:80%;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
#price {
  background: green;
  display: inline-block;
}

.menu-ingredients {
  
}
#ingredients {
  
}
```

```html
<div class="menu-item">
  <div class="menu-title">
    <div id="number">23</div>
    <div id="dish">Souvlaki</div>
    <div id="price">495 kr</div>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-ingredients">
    <div id="ingredients">Pizza, hamburger, cucumber, tomato</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="menu-item">
  <div class="menu-title">
    <div id="number">40</div>
    <div id="dish">RAVIOLI CON PIPIENO DI GRANICHI E RICOTTA AL FINOCCHIO E SALSINA DI ARRAGOSTA

</div>
    <div id="price">9000 kr</div>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-ingredients">
    <div id="ingredients">Ravioli filled with crab and ricotta. Servec with minicucumber and cheese from Gotland. Shrimps toghether with peanuts and pumpkin</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try `.menu-title {
display:flex;
}`
and 
`#dish {
  flex-grow: 1;
}`

see [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/80s6h9km/)